# How to add controls to the top when extend the content search webpart

Tags: 2013, content-search-web-part

I created webpart inherit ContentBySearchWebpart, in this webpart i added a textbox and a button.

By default, the textbox and the button are below the content search webpart, how to move them to the top?

Please help...

Here are my code:

```
public class CustomSearch : ContentBySearchWebPart

 protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = "tbProjectName";

            Button bt = new Button();
            bt.ID = "btSubmit";
            bt.Text = "Submit";
            bt.Click += bt_Click;

            Controls.AddAt(0,tb);
            Controls.AddAt(1,bt);


            base.CreateChildControls();

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "buttons are below the content search web part"? They are _inside_ the web part. Would you like to move them _outside_ the web part, above the web part title?

Comment: Hi Palo, in the CreateChildControl method , I created a textbox and a button, and use Controls.Add(textbox), Controls.Add(button) to extend the base Content Search Webpart. My newly created controls are below the original CSWP, I want to move them at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AddAt to inject control to specific location in Controls collection.

```
Controls.AddAt(0, button)
Controls.AddAt(0, textbox)
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.addat(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I already tried this, and it's  not working.

Comment: base.CreateChildControls(); will add controls after your controls. Try moving it to top.

Comment: Also tried... :(